# ARG substitution in RUN command not working for Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I have the following:

```
ARG a-version
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/alle.tar.gz http://someserver/server/$a-version/a-server-$a-version.tar.gz && \
    mkdir /opt/apps/$a-version
```

However when building this with:

```
--build-arg http_proxy=http://myproxy","--build-arg a-version=a","--build-arg b-version=b"
```

`Step 10/15 : RUN wget...` is shown with `$a-version` in the path instead of the substituted value and the build fails.

I have followed the instructions shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) but must be missing something else.

> My questions is, what could be causing this issue and how can i solve
>   it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't use `-` in variable names.

Docker build will always show you the line as is written down in the Dockerfile, despite the variable value.

So use this variable name `a_version`:

```
ARG a_version
```

See this example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

ARG a_version
RUN echo $a_version
```

Build:

```
$ docker build . --build-arg a_version=1234
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> a41a7446062d
Step 2/3 : ARG a_version
 ---> Running in c55e98cab494
 ---> 53dedab7de75
Removing intermediate container c55e98cab494
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $a_version                <<< note this <<
 ---> Running in 56b8aeddf77b
1234                                          <<<< and this <<
 ---> 89badadc1ccf
Removing intermediate container 56b8aeddf77b
Successfully built 89badadc1ccf
```

Comment: I got this problem as well. But - does not seem to be the cause. My ARG name is privKeyFile, no matter what I tried, the value while building is always empty.

Comment: As per @Oleg comment below, try adding quotes around the variable (e.g. `"$privKeyFile"`). This solved the same problem for me. Oddly, quotes seems to be a requirement only on Windows, because everything works fine on MacOS without quotes.

Answer (score 362):

Another thing to be careful about is that after every `FROM` statement, all the `ARG`s get collected and are no longer available. Be careful with multi-stage builds.

You can reuse `ARG` with omitted default value inside `FROM` to get through this problem:

```
ARG VERSION=latest
FROM busybox:$VERSION
ARG VERSION
RUN echo $VERSION > image_version
```

Example taken from docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: I think you can work around this by copying an ARG into an ENV. 
```ARG OSVERSION
ENV OSVERSION=${OSVERSION:10}```

Comment: Gotta love the randomness of docker files.  Of course ARGS would disappear after from... of course....

Comment: so many tutorials use `ENV` workarounds because they haven't understand that `ARG` needs to be requested in every stage. Thanks for sharing, helped a lot! upvote

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when passing the arg in with --build-args. It might be a kaniko problem though, I am passing --build-args to kaniko...

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem using Windows containers for Windows.

Instead of doing this (Which works in linux containers)

```
FROM alpine
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN echo "I'm building for $TARGETPLATFORM"
```

You need to do this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN echo "I'm building for %TARGETPLATFORM%"
```

Just change the variable resolution according to the OS.

Comment: This is also my solution with Docker 19.0.3 and Windows 10 v1809.  I don't think this is mentioned in the Docker documentation.

Comment: I tried the other suggestions with quotes like `RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive "$NAME".zip` etc., but only this worked! `RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive %NAME%.zip`

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me on a Windows container. Thanks!

Comment: What a life saver, I struggled a lot with variable substituition on Windows (running Windows Containers). This answer is the only place Ive found this information. Thanks a million.

Comment: spent almost a day trying to find the reason whey ARG was not working on windows image... Thanks... "%ARG_NAME%" works on windows image.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the `%VAR%` substitution is only needed under `RUN`; for `ADD`, the Dockerfile expects the regular `${VAR}` substitution...

Answer (score 19):

I spent much time to have the argument substitution working, but the solution was really simple. The substitution within `RUN` needs the argument reference to be enclosed in double quotes.

```
ARG CONFIGURATION=Debug
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c "$CONFIGURATION" -o /app/publish
```

Answer (score 13):

The only way I was able to substitute an ARG in a Windows Container was to prefix with `$env:`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2232#issuecomment-407017705).

An example of my Dockerfile is below. Notice that the `ARG PAT` is defined **after** the FROM so that it's in scope for its use in the `RUN nuget sources add` command ([as Hongtao suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56748289/4597249)). The only successful way I found to supply the personal access token was using `$env:PAT`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app

ARG PAT

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY WebApi/*.csproj ./WebApi/
COPY WebApi/*.config ./WebApi/
RUN nuget sources add -name AppDev -source https://mysource.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AppDev/nuget/v2 -username usern -password $env:PAT
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY WebApi/. ./WebApi/
WORKDIR /app/WebApi
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/WebApi/. ./
```

The actual Docker command looks like this:

`docker build --build-arg PAT=mypatgoeshere -t webapi .`

Comment: Might this have to do with difference in `SHELL` declarations? This was the only solution that worked for me and I'm not clear why. (FWIW, mine is `SHELL ["powershell", ...]`.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem accessing `build-args` in my `RUN` command. Turns out that the line containing the `ARG` definition should not be the first line. The working `Dockerfile` snippet looks like this:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER xxxxx

ARG SERVER_IPS
```

Earlier, I had placed the `ARG` definition as the first line of `Dockerfile` . My docker version is v19.

Answer (score 4):

There are many answers, which make sense.
But the main thing is missed.

The way, how to use build arguments **depends on the base image**.

- For Linux image, it will work with `$ARG`
- For Windows, depending on image, it can be either `$env:ARG`(e.g. for *mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8*) or %ARG% (e.g. for *mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809*)

Answer (score 2):

For me it was argument's order:

`docker build . -f somepath/to/Dockerfile --build-arg FOO=BAR`

did not work, but:

`docker build --build-arg FOO=BAR . -f somepath/to/Dockerfile`

did.

Comment: I spent 5 hours fighting with this building an windows image. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

Also be aware that (now) you can not use arguments in `COPY --from`:

```
COPY --from=company/mu_library:${BUILD_CONFIG} /some/path /other/path
```

As a workaround you can create a build stage with that image using the argument:

```
FROM company/mu_library:${BUILD_CONFIG} as mu-library
COPY --from=mu-library /some/path /other/path
```

Answer copied from Docker King [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303997/5233188), related [Docker issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482).