# Interpolating strings in a file path in a DockerFile

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-cli, string-interpolation

I have a Docker file which starts like this:

```
ARG FILE_PATH

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["${FILE_PATH}/src/NuGet.config", "src/"]
```

I call it using the azure-cli like this:

```
$pathToSrc = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/My folder"

az acr build --build-arg "FILE_PATH=$pathToSrc" ...
```

This always fails with the message:

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
> .dockerignore: stat src/NuGet.config: file does not exist

I have tried variations such as:

```
COPY [$FILE_PATH/src/NuGet.config, "src/"]
COPY ["FILE_PATH/src/NuGet.config", "src/"]
```

and

```
az acr build --build-arg "FILE_PATH='$pathToSrc'" ...
```

but always end up with the same message.

Is there a way to do this. I am running on a hosted agent in Azure-devops pipeline. The task is task: AzureCLI@2 using a PowerShell Core script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56748289/4424236

> ...after every `FROM` statements all the `ARG`s gets collected and are no longer available. Be careful with multi-stage builds.

Try this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src

ARG FILE_PATH

COPY ["${FILE_PATH}/src/NuGet.config", "src/"]
```