# Files needed to run a container docker-compose command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I think I have a bit of a hard time understanding what files do I need to be able to run a container with my Rails app on an empty instance.

I have a `docker-compose.prod.yml` that I want to run:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-default}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-default}
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: "username/repo:${WEB_TAG:-latest}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
      - log-data:/myapp/log
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-default}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-default}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST:-default}
  web:
    build: nginx
    volumes:
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
volumes:
  public-data:
  tmp-data:
  log-data:
  db-data:
```

So, in the instance, I have the `docker-compose.prod.yml` file. And since I am passing variables for the environments and the image web tag, I created an `.env` file with those variables in it as well. Finally, since I am building `nginx`, I have a folder with the image:

```
FROM arm64v8/nginx

# インクルード用のディレクトリ内を削除
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Nginxの設定ファイルをコンテナにコピー
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/myapp.conf

# ビルド完了後にNginxを起動
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;' -c /etc/nginx/myapp.conf
```

and config file `nginx.conf`

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;

events{
    worker_connections  512;
}

# ソケット接続
http {
  upstream myapp{
    server unix:///myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
  }
  server { # simple load balancing
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    #ログを記録しようとするとエラーが生じます
    #root /myapp/public;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
  }
}
```

So, `docker-compose.prod.yml`, `nginx` directory with the 2 files and the `.env` file.

When I do: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml --env-file .env run app rake db:create db:migrate` it downloads the `postgres` and `app` images but once it starts doing the `rake` for the `db:create db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for user/repo:48
Creating rails-app_db_1 ... done
Creating rails-app_app_run ... done
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

but then when I add the `Rakefile`, it keeps asking for other dependents files so either I need the whole project itself (clone it from my repo on GitHub) or I am doing this wrong.

Any ideas on what files do I need or if I need to change commands are welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `docker-compose.yml` file says

```yaml
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
```

It means the contents of the `/myapp` directory in your image – probably the entire application – are ignored and replaced with whatever's in your host directory.  So with this setup you need to copy the entire application source code, or it won't work.

But also:

```yaml
volumes:
  - public-data:/myapp/public
```

Your application's static assets are being stored in a Docker named volume.  This is hard to transfer between systems, and it will ignore any changes in the underlying image.

---

I'd update a couple of things in this setup, both to avoid most of the volumes and to make things a little easier to work with.

Docker has an internal networking layer, and you can communicate between containers using their Compose service names as host names.  (See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.)  That means you can set the Nginx reverse proxy to talk to the Rails app over normal HTTP/TCP

```
upstream myapp {
  server http://app:9292; # or the port from your config.ru/puma.rb file
}
```

This eliminates the need for the `tmp-data` volume.

In the same way you're building your application code into an image, you can also build the static assets into an image.  Update the Nginx image Dockerfile to look like:

```sh
# Artificial build stage to include app; https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303997
ARG appimage
FROM ${appimage} AS app

FROM arm64v8/nginx

# Replace the Nginx configuration
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy in the static assets
COPY --from=app /myapp/public /myapp/public

# Use the default CMD from the base image; no need to rewrite it
```

This removes the need for the `public-data` volume.

In your main application image, you should declare an `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` so you don't need to repeat the long-winded `command:`.  For the `ENTRYPOINT`, I'd suggest a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Remove a stale pid file
rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid

# Run the main container CMD under Bundler
exec bundle exec "$@"
```

Make sure this file is executable (`chmod +x entrypoint.sh`) and add it to your repository, maybe in the top-level directory next to your `Dockerfile` and `Gemfile`.  In the Dockerfile, declare this script as the `ENTRYPOINT`, and make Puma be the `CMD`:

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]       # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"] # could be shell syntax
```

The only volume mounts we haven't touched are the database storage and the log directory.  For the database storage, a Docker named volume could be appropriate, since you never need to look at the files directly.  A named volume is substantially faster on some platforms (MacOS and some cases of Windows) but is harder to transfer between systems.  Conversely, for the logs, I'd use a bind mount, since you do generally want to read them directly from the host system.

This reduces the `docker-compose.yml` file to:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  db: { unchanged: from the original question }
  app:
    image: "username/repo:${WEB_TAG:-latest}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/log:/myapp/log
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-default}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-default}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST:-default}
  web:
    image: "username/web:${WEB_TAG:-latest}"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
```

We've removed almost all of the `volumes:`, and all of the references to host directories except for the database storage and a directory to output the logs.  We've also removed the `command:` override as repeating what's in the Dockerfile.  (In other similar SO questions, I might remove unnecessary `networks:`, `container_name:`, and `hostname:` declarations, along with obsolete `links:` and `expose:` options.)

If you've done this, you need a way to build your images and push them to the repository.  You can have [a second Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) that *only* describes how to build the images:

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
# in the same directory as docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
  web:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      args:
        appimage: username/repo:${WEB_TAG:-latest}
```

Compose's one shortcoming in this situation is that it doesn't know that the one image depends on the other.  This means you need to manually build the base image first.

```sh
export WEB_TAG=20220305
docker-compose build app
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

This seems like a lot of setup.  But having done this, the only thing we need to copy to the new system is the `docker-compose.yml` file and the production `.env` settings.

```sh
# on the local system
scp docker-compose.yml .env there:
```

```sh
# on the remote system
export WEB_TAG=20220305
docker-compose run app \
  rake db:create db:migrate
docker-compose up -d
```

Docker will automatically pull the images from the repository if it doesn't have a copy locally.  (It's helpful, and required in contexts like Kubernetes, to use a unique image tag per build; `docker system prune` can clean up old unused images.)  If you give the files their default names `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` then you don't need to mention them on the command line.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I am trying to understand all the steps you pointed out. In this one (when we build the images): 
```export WEB_TAG=20220305
docker-compose build app
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```
The idea behind it is to call the `docker-compose.override.yml` right? If we have both `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` when we build the image we don't need to specifically write `-f docker-compose.override.yml` ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you have both a `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` then [Compose reads both by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Comment: Thanks! So I have a `docker-compose.prod.yml` file that is the one that holds the `nginx` config for the container. The `docker-compose.yml` doesn't have it. It is just a simple `app and db` config without the `nginx` that I used for testing and developing. Is it better to not have a different `docker-compose.prod.yml` and a `docker-compose.yml` so that testing, development and production follow the same `docker-compose` file? Thanks in advance!