# Docker Build Argument Not Set

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I cannot figure out why I cannot interpolate a build argument within the bash of a docker `RUN` command.

Here's a simple Dockerfile, where I use the Build argument as a tag release for a second image (just to test it's working), and then I try to make a directory with the same name in the main image.

```
ARG FOO=latest

FROM python:${FOO} as bar
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye

COPY --from=bar /bin/sh /whatever

RUN mkdir "$FOO"
```

```
$ sudo docker build --rm .                                                                                                                        •◦◦ main
[+] Building 0.4s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                                     docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 162B                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-bullseye                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                     0.0s
 => [bar 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim-bullseye                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] COPY --from=bar /bin/sh /whatever                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/3] RUN mkdir "$FOO"                                                                                                             0.3s
------
 > [stage-1 3/3] RUN mkdir "$FOO":
0.319 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     COPY --from=bar /bin/sh /whatever
   7 |     
   8 | >>> RUN mkdir "$FOO"
   9 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mkdir \"$FOO\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Presumably something silly, though what made me notice this is a old Dockerfile that I assume use to work, but no longer does, because of these build arguments.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARG substitution in RUN command not working for Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438637/arg-substitution-in-run-command-not-working-for-dockerfile)

Comment: (Oddly, the highest-scored [answer](/a/56748289) to that question is right, but it doesn't seem to actually match the question.)